# probability after $n$ selections($n>1$),the product of $n$ numbers selected will be divisible by $10$

Tags: probability

A random selector can only select one of the nine integers $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$ and it makes these selections with equal probability.prove that the probability after $n$ selections($n>1$),the product of $n$ numbers selected will be divisible by $10$ is $1-\left(\frac{8}{9}\right)^n-\left(\frac{5}{9}\right)^n+\left(\frac{4}{9}\right)^n$

I do not know how to start with this problem,some hints and suggestions are needed.

Comment: Same as:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/984919/probability-a-product-of-n-randomly-chosen-numbers-from-1-9-is-divisible-by-10

Answer (score 1):

Hint :

The product number will be divisible by 10, if and only if a 5 and a multiple of 2 are selected

Answer (score 1):

Hint - you need both $5$ and an even number to get a multiple of $10$. Compute the number of ways of choosing no multiples of $5$ and then separately number of ways of choosing no even numbers. Eliminate the double-counting.